# Neo4j Graph DB - how to make computations over the whole graph with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, neo4j

I have a neo4j graph db with 4 million nodes and 100 million relationships. I try to compute a number for all adjacent node pairs (basically for all edges), using an algorithm which uses for all nodes the number of incoming, outgoing edges, and also the numbers of all incoming edges of all outgoing edges.

I am using the Java API but I realized that to get these incoming edges of all outgoing edges is very slow. I tried to get all these data and making the computations using multiple threads, and it became much better, but still it takes several seconds (sometimes 30s) for a given node and for all of its adjacent edges. (without threads it can take 15 minutes). So if I want to do this computation for all edges, than I should reach the couple of ms time frame per node.

So I would ask, what are the general strategies to use multiple threads - and how - with embedded neo4j graph db (say on a quadcore 4G laptop?).

Comment: you have not provided enough information to answer this.  What algorithm are you using?

Answer (score 0):

is this the first or second run that you are measuring? If it is the first then it is because of cold cache and loading the data into memory.

You should probably also look into configuring your JVM settings and Neo4j cache.

See: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/embedded-configuration.html

Comment: thanks for your answer...with the jvm settings i had enough experience when i did the batch insert, so in this case, i think my jvm settings are good. The problem is, that i want to do this computation in one run so to say and for the whole graph, i.e. for all edges and of course using transactions as I want to write the computed numbers into the graph back! So after many experiments now I have the speed 3500 links per minute, which is not bad, but for 100 million edges it is hopeless. I plan to try out the algorithm on a "bigger" machine, such that I could load into the memory the whole graph

Comment: Try to use a ssd for faster loading of your data into memory, and also the neo4j enterprice gcr cache which is more efficient.